# Convert word into specific Part Of Speech (POS) format?

Tags: nlp, nltk

Given a word, is it possible, using NLTK, to convert that word into a specific Part Of Speech (POS) form?  For example, given the word "run", can I ask NLTK to convert it to any of the following:

```
VBZ: runs, as in "George runs to the store."
VBD: ran,  as in "George ran to the store."
VB:  run,  as in "George wants to run."
```

Etc. If yes, same for nouns? e.g.:

```
NN:  run,  as in "George wants to run."
NNS: runs, as in "George went for two runs."
NNP: Run,  as in "George had dinner at Run."
```

Comment: "To run" is definitely a verb. For NN, maybe "George went for a run."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try [pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en)

It has features like:

- Pluralization + singularization
- Comparative + superlative
- Verb conjugation
- Quantification

Hope this helps.